# Convert String Into array separated by square brackets

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string which contains several square brackets. I need to get the values as array separated by the square brackets. 
My example will make you sense:

`$inputString = "['A'|'AA']['B'|'BB']['C'|'CC']";`

My objective is to get the array like this:

```
0=>'A'|'AA'
1=>'B'|'BB'
2=>'C'|'CC'
```

Comment: It is not clear what you intend the values of your associate array to actually be.  What is `'A'|'AA'` ?

Comment: Showing our attempts and where you are having problems both helps in understanding the problem as well as shows you have made some effort.

Comment: The first A represents an image path and the next AA represents its title. The data is too large. So I use A,B,AA like this.

Answer (score 2):

Remove first and last brackets, then use `explode` function.

```
$inputString = "['A'|'AA']['B'|'BB']['C'|'CC']";
$inputString = rtrim($inputString,"]");
$inputString = ltrim($inputString,"[");
print_r(explode("][", $inputString));
/*Array
(
  [0] => 'A'|'AA'
  [1] => 'B'|'BB'
  [2] => 'C'|'CC'
)*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using PHP explode function..

```
$inputString = "['A'|'AA']['B'|'BB']['C'|'CC']";
$inputString=str_replace("["," ",$inputString);
print_r (explode("]",rtrim($inputString,"]")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$inputString = "['A'|'AA']['B'|'BB']['C'|'CC']";
$obj = str_replace("]","",str_replace("[","",explode("][", $inputString)));
print_r($obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

using `preg_match_all`

```
$inputString = "['A'|'AA']['B'|'BB']['C'|'CC']";
preg_match_all('#\[(.*?)\]#', $inputString, $array);
print_r($array[1]);
```